# SDK 2.0: Controlling the X Axis in rallychart

Tags: rally

I'm trying to create a defect create/kill chart for defects using rallychart in SDK 2.0.  The X axis is time-- in this case either individual days, weeks or months.

I don't see any examples of how to control the X-Axis using rallychart.  How do you do it?  Do you use categories directly in highcharts?  How should you configure the data store?

In general, what are some ways to do time based graphs using rallychart?

Comment: We are still working on an example App that uses the charting components. The SDK will have components in them before the examples that use them are released. We will be sure to share some examples as soon as we have them ready.

Comment: What sort of timeframe do you think we are looking at?  Days vs. Weeks vs. Months vs. > 6 Months?  Just trying to determine if I should wait  or go my own way-- thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just pass a chartConfig (including x-axis categories and your series data) and that will be passed through to highcharts.  I'm not sure if this works in 2.0p2 or not but it should in 2.0p3 when that is released.

Comment: The thing that confuses me here is that Rally Chart takes an ext-js data store, but highcharts use particular arrays that are not data stores.  Say for example I provide a data store that is an array of objects, and one element of each object is a date {date: 2012-02-02, created: 10, killed: 5}. I can define all the relevant dates as categories, but how will Highcharts know to associate the date in the object with the date in the category?

Comment: The store is optional and kind of a weird way to use the component IMHO.  I am reasonably sure that if you just pass in a chartConfig (with the appropriate x axis categories and series) it should work in the 2.0p3 version.